# Error compiling Go from source in an Alpine Docker container: "loadinternal: cannot find runtime/cgo"

Tags: docker, go, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build an Alpine Docker image for the FIPS-enabled version of Go. To do this, I am trying to build Go from source using the `dev.boringcrypto` branch of the `golang/go` repository.

Upon running `./all.bash`, I get the following errors:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN cd go/src && ./all.bash
 ---> Running in 00db552598f7
Building Go cmd/dist using /usr/lib/go.
# _/go/src/cmd/dist
loadinternal: cannot find runtime/cgo
/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64- 
alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64- 
alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lssp_nonshared
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The command '/bin/bash -c cd go/src && ./all.bash' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Which causes the installation tests to fail and kicks me out of the Docker image build.

I have the `gcc` installed on the image, and tried setting the environment variable `CGO_ENABLED=0` as suggested in other questions, but neither of these things seem to alleviate the problem.

I'm at my wits end with this problem. Has anybody else run into similar issues in the past? I don't understand why this is happening, as the build runs fine in an Ubuntu container.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error messages, although I was compiling a different project.

It turns out that alpine needs to have the `musl-dev` package installed for this to work, so I think you need to make sure that is included in your Dockerfile, or manually install it by running `apk add --no-cache musl-dev`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Code gave output, but getting this message (warning) on build time `loadinternal: cannot find runtime/cgo`.

Answer (score 2):

Either go isn't correctly installed on the image or the GOROOT is wrong

Put `go tool dist banner` and `go tool dist env` in your all.bash for clues